# scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator with optional keyword argument

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to create a linear operator with `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator` from a function which has an optional keyword argument, e.g `myfunc(x,y=0)`, so that I can change the parameter in the resulting linear operator. Does anyone know if that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your instance of `LinearOperator`, its parameter must be set.  When you change that parameter, you are changing the linear operator.

If you have a function `myfunc` that implements your linear operator, I imagine the quickest/easiest way to achieve what you want is to pass a lambda function to `LinearOperator` that passes your parameter value to `myfunc`.

E.g.

```py
# `myfunc` implements the matrix-vector product for your linear operator
def myfunc(x, y=0):
    '''Implments the matrix-vector product for vector `x` and additional parameter `y`'''
    pass

shape =  # <the shape of your linear operator>
y =  # <the value of the parameter you want to use>
L = LinearOperator(shape, matvec=lambda x: myfunc(x, y))

# Then you can do:
x =  # <some vector>
b = L @ x  # note: `@` is the matrix multiply operation
# Now `b` will contain the result of `myfunc(x, y)
```